# Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, policy, community-wiki

Every so often I run into a question which I think should be community wiki.  I am usually not sure about flagging since some of them have been around for a while and the question of why did noone else suggest it comes up.  Also I am confused about how questions are chosen to be community wiki.

Just some examples:  [Calculus Today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58104/what-is-the-importance-of-calculus-in-todays-mathematics), [Prestige](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/does-it-ever-make-sense-not-to-go-to-the-most-prestigious-graduate-school-you-can/), [Publishing Theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55864/how-does-one-know-that-a-theorem-is-strong-enough-to-publish/).  In particular the question of why did none of the answerers suggest it comes up as well, since in the above examples, many of the answerers are very experienced users.

Are the above good examples of community wiki questions?  Why or why not.  Should I just flag in any case if I think so? What is the appropriate response?

I know there is [another thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/445/what-questions-should-be-community-wiki) related to this topic, but I don't find that thread too helpful.  (Also, the answers haven't been voted up very much which usually means the community is not in agreement)

Thanks,

Comment: I flagged my question (Calculus Today) to make it into a CW.

Comment: "Should I just flag in any case if I think so?" Yes. Sometimes the question maybe a bit borderline and even the moderators would like to know that at least one other non-mod user thinks the same. Also, mods cannot be everywhere at the same time.

Comment: I've converted all of three to CW, just in case people are wondering. (BTW, the middle one was kinda old, and before any of the current mods became mods.)

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thanks for the conversion.

Comment: In 33 question only two questions, this one "What is the importance of Calculus in today's Mathematics?" [Calculus Today] and "What does closed form solution usually mean?" are "soft" questions. It is my intention not to ask "soft" questions in the main site anymore.

Answer (score 11):

IMO, all questions that have no objective right answer but asks for a list of opinions should be CW. In particular, all questions mentioned in post should be CW (if not closed — but let's restrict our discussion to CW policy, for a moment).

Comment: (We haven't reached community agreement last time, indeed. Let's try again?)

Comment: Yesterday I flagged my question (Calculus Today) to make it into a CW. Is was converted to CW yesterday by Willie Wong ♦.

Comment: "It was converted" instead of "Is was converted".

Comment: I didn't read the comment thread in Shog9's answer and also only glanced at the long blog post he linked to both tl;dr. However, it seems to me that the "automatic CW-fication" of certain questions, especially questions asking for references on a more specialized topic, might be counter productive. Specialized is intended to mean "no very strong user base here". For instance, there is this question on [numerical analysis](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/58881/) which might be a better question, of course. I think there aren't that many users able to say much more...

Comment: ...than what Google spits out after the first two or three most obvious searches, so leaving the question non-CW might induce one or two good answers motivated by reputation. Yes, it belongs to the good tone to say one doesn't care about reputation but still I think it does its job quite well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking a question should be CW because it can't garner useful, objective answers... Then you should probably just vote to close it. [From the FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask):

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about `______`”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain `______` to me”, then you are probably OK.

(and also the [guidelines for asking subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), linked to from the FAQ)

If it's actual, *useful* stuff, then [CW isn't necessary](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/):

> Instead, strive for quality. If you’re unsure a certain question class belongs on the site, don’t tolerate the worst examples — demand that these questions be awesome. Questions shouldn’t be swept under the rug with community wiki; they should get the same respect and treatment as the rest of your Q&A. If those questions are something you are uncomfortable showing to visitors … they probably don’t belong on your site.

Why *would* you need Community Wiki on a question? [Well...](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)

> Sometimes you have content which is valuable and on-topic, but is perhaps a bit too popular. It runs the risk of overwhelming the rest of your site if it grows untamed. In these circumstances, community wiki can be a way to preserve the value of these posts while stifling their growth. Keep in mind, though, that in using community wiki to stifle growth, you should actually follow through with it — a site should never have more than one community wiki question for every hundred questions. Having too many community wiki questions defeats the entire purpose.

So again, first ask yourself if the question even belongs on the site. Then ask if it could be structured so as to encourage high-quality responses. Finally, *if* the question belongs, encourages *and* is receiving good answers, ask yourself if there's a really good reason why the site should encourage editing existing answers over posting new ones - *that* would be when you might ask for it to be made Community Wiki.

Comment: Maybe things are different here, but on MathOverflow Community Wiki is often used for questions of the form "Give me some examples of ...."

Comment: @Gerry: this doesn't seem to be universal (even here), but then you guys have both [tag:soft-question] (equivalent to the [subjective] tag on SO that was killed a year ago) and [tag:big-list] (= [poll]). If CW can aid in encouraging wiki-like behavior (editing...) over runaway Q&A (absurd numbers of answers), then fine, but... the crucial first question is still, "does this even belong here"

Comment: Now, when anybody can suggest edits, the main effect of CW is not that answers can be edited, but that they _don't generate rep_, IMHO...

Comment: `@Shog9` Well, my point is, let's have a clear CW policy -- that _can be enforced by moderators quickly_ -- and after question is CW already, community can decide, whether it should be closed (which is a long process with unpredictable results, it seems).

Comment: I wrote the first example [Calculus Today](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58104/what-is-the-importance-of-calculus-in-todays-mathematics). Since it is "quite poorly-written", I would appreciate someone edit it. As far as the CW question, I will make my question a CW.

Comment: I flagged my question (Calculus Today) to make it into a CW.

Comment: @Grigory If the main purpose of CW becomes "no reputation", you then have to think for yourself - "Is it worth anything to this site?" If something is valuable to the site, it *should* generate reputation - you want to encourage the value you want to harvest. It's a lot more rewarding when a person is recognized for their efforts for providing value, so if it is something you find valuable enough to warrant a place on the site, it probably shouldn't be Community Wiki. If it isn't valuable, then you want to think long and hard about whether you really want to keep it around at all.

Comment: @Grace Your definition of valuable looks somewhat... 1-dimensional to me: I find... good poetry, for example, valuable — but still don't think that posting it on math.SE should generate rep. And it's more or less the same thing with some questions and answers: community finds them _valuable_ enough to have but not... let's say _on-topic_ enough to generate rep.

Comment: @Grigory I mean valuable to the site. Most poetry isn't of use to the site, but if something is desired to be on-topic and kept on the site, that it is something you want people to see when coming to the site and enjoy, then it should be something people can contribute to with full acknowledgement. If it is something you want to show off on the site, then you want people to feel it is worth it to contribute the best to make it shine its greatest. If it isn't something you want to show off, then perhaps Community Wiki solely for removing reputation is perhaps apt.

Comment: @GrigoryM: moderators can close just as fast as they can CW a post. So if you have to ask a moderator to step in anyway (which you do for CW), you might as well ask for closing if that's more appropriate. Note that the community can override a moderator's close vote, but CW is irreversible (without further moderator intervention).

Comment: @Grace, Shog: This approach is once again, in my opinion, a bad example to the approach which is useful on SO and not on MSE. The logic is that if it is valuable it should generate reputation is exactly to say if it does not generate reputation then it is invaluable. In this **small** community it is possible to reach a consensus within the core of users about valuable things. Reputation is just a bonus. Therefore things are valuable if they are valuable, and things generate reputation if they do that. The two notions are not completely orthogonal, but they are far from being the same.

Comment: @Asaf My logic is that if you think that these soft questions are a valuable resource that you want people to find on this site, I have difficulty understanding why you would want to mark them Community Wiki. Vote-wise, they are on the exact same scale as contributions of "hard" questions, the image they provide for the site, to symbolize the community, doesn't change. All Community Wiki does is deny recognition to the authors of those contributions, and so if you want them to sit beside your hard content as quality voted material, I'm strained to see an actual benefit to marking them as such.

Comment: @Grace: Reputation is not everything on this website. In particular, I think that reputation should come from accurate and well posed answers to questions which has such answer available. Subjective questions *are still valuable* but I do not agree that reputation *must* be earned from these. People may very well pay me to paint their house (a bad idea, though) but they will not pay me any money for voicing an agreeable opinion. They will, however, show a vote of confidence and say they support my idea. This is the correct analogy, I believe, here.

Comment: @Asaf Agreed. I don't think reputation is everything, either. Votes on Community Wiki posts don't mean anything different than they do on other posts, a fact that holds true to your analogy that both objective and subjective material is valuable. I accept that sometimes, people use Community Wiki to allow content which is indeed valuable, but which is not to be fostered or encouraged, and I won't oppose that even if I don't fully agree with it. I nevertheless stand by my point, many times Community Wiki isn't necessary, and I'd rather people dwell on that, even if they don't yield to that.

Comment: @Asaf: what you're missing here is that we *tried* this on SO, starting when the site was considerably smaller than it is now. I've made arguments similar to yours. I've forced "soft" questions into CW, and encouraged others to do likewise. We built up rules, protocols, standards... And it all came to naught. Maybe you'll make it work; maybe you'll stay small, and come up with a cohesive set of rules for when "rep denial" is appropriate that can be explained easily to new users. But I don't see that it's happened - as Eric noted, this came up before, and... no real consensus was reached.

Comment: @Shog9: Not to be dismissive, but the required level of maturity in the core users of SO seems be quite below that of the core level of MSE. Mostly because mathematics require a level of maturity which is less required for general programming (although it sure does contribute a lot when it is there). By this virtue the core users of MSE learn very well that sometimes one steps down from the reputation chase and writes an opinion they strongly believe in. And heck, if not for the reputation, there's always badges to chase :-)

Comment: @Asaf: And I'll freely admit, I'm more familiar with the core users on SO than I am with the core users here... But, it isn't the *core* users who broke attempts to make this work on SO: it was an ever-larger stream of *new* users, whose pressure the core could not withstand; in the end, it literally *ripped the site in two*! So if you stay small, if the number of new users arriving here never grows beyond a trickle, then it doesn't really matter what you do, or whether or not the rules are explicit. But the question then becomes: are you willing to bet your policy on obscurity?

Comment: In 33 question only two questions, this one "What is the importance of Calculus in today's Mathematics?" [Calculus Today] and "What does closed form solution usually mean?" are "soft" questions. It is my intention not to ask "soft" questions in the main site anymore.

Comment: Yesterday I added to the question "What is the importance of Calculus in today's Mathematics?" [Calculus Today]  three comments of mine to it.

Comment: @Grace, Shog9: It appears to me, that again this is a very good example for dissonance between the math community and the big SO developers. Let me put it in this analogy, people who write in C their entire lives might not understand how can someone stand Common Lisp. Or Haskell. And to be fair, I see two options for a potential growth: the first is mature users who accept and understand the role of CW; the second is an explosion of reputation-chasing folks, trolls and so on. In which case, I will be leaving anyway.