# Wiki and non-wiki posts

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

What is the difference between a wiki post and a non-wiki post?
I'm not too old member of stack exchange so I don't know much about this. So someone please give an answer regarding the question.

Comment: I'll add that links to some basic information are collected in the [tag-info for community-wiki tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info). (As is often the case.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main idea behind a Community Wiki (CW) post is that it has many different contributors.

As a consequence a CW post:

- has a lower point threshold for editing (100 versus 2000).
- does not give its owner reputation from votes.

There are some other minor differences, for details you can see [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

The default is that a post is **not** CW. When exactly something should be CW is a matter of debate. See for example:

- [Community Wiki?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/community-wiki)
- [CW-ikification: why?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2938/cw-ikification-why)
- [What questions should be community wiki?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/445/what-questions-should-be-community-wiki)

Yet, as a casual user I would say you can more-or-less ignore that feature. A few points to keep in mind:

- If ever you decide to repost the content of some comments of others as an answer, you may want to make this answer CW (check the box at the lower right corner of the input box). [Note self CW-ing questions is not possible anymore.]
- If you come across a question that is CW you might keep in mind that your answer will then also be CW and you will not get points from it (if you care about that).

Comment: What is the difference between casual and hardcore user in you sense ?

Comment: Mostly it is about whether a user wants to get involved in moderation, maintainance tasks, and discussion about policy, or just wants to use the site for regular Q&A. Though for CW specicfically in my mind it is somewhat of a legacy feature so is rarely relevant these days even for power users.